# What are the solutions for avoiding "that"?

Tags: javascript, closures, this, settimeout, javascript-objects

So take following simple javascript class snippet:

```
var Class = function() {
    this.publicvar = 1;

    this.privileged = function() {
        return this.publicvar;
    };
};
var c = new Class();
setTimeout(c.privileged, 1);                    //c.this -> window
```

Obviously this won't work, "this" will be the window object. So at this point we can do a var that=this, and use that.publicvar, OR, we can do this.

```
setTimeout(function() { c.privileged() }, 1);   //c.this -> Class
```

What a great solution and easy fix, now I don't have to put "that" all over the place in my class. Not to mention, using "that" gets much more complicated when using an object.prototype.publicMethod.

So, my question is: What are the other cases where you would have to worry about the "this" in "this.publicvar" being binded to the window context, and what is the solution to each? (I'm hoping we have a solution for every single one of them so I never have to use that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Function`'s `bind`:

```
setTimeout(c.privileged.bind(c), 1);
```

Or you could pre`bind` in the constructor, but this could be rather unexpected in JS whereas it is the default in Python:

```
var Class = function() {
    this.publicvar = 1;

    this.privileged = (function() {
        return this.publicvar;
    }).bind(this);
};
var c = new Class();
setTimeout(c.privileged, 1);
```